# how to save outputs from a .sh script in windows folder?

Tags: windows-10, bash, folder-redirection

I have this piece of code, it converts process a .shp file and run few lines with the original saving an output and  subproceswith different name and saving them in a new folder (build), it  works perfectly in UNIX (Ubuntu 20.x.x)but I would like to save this in windows folders.
I am running Ubuntu 20.x in WSL in windows 10.

This is the piece of the code where the output are set and where the folder build should be created:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    
    # === variables =======================
    
    var_1="path/to/file"
    var_2="$(echo $var_1 | sed "s/^.*\///" | sed "s/\.shp$//")"
    
    
    LAYER=layer_name
    
    OUT_SHP=build/$LAYER.shp
    OUT_JSON=build/$LAYER.json
    OUT_MBTILES=build/$LAYER.mbtiles

OUT_MBTILES=build/$LAYER.mbtiles
```

My first idea was to ./build/$LAYER.shp so it will create a folder called build where the script is, independently if it is ubuntu or Windows, but the result is that it creates the folder build with the files in unix_user@DESKTOP-llmmnn:~$ in ubuntu and not in /mnt/c/script/shp/.

Any idea about how can I save the outputs in windows folder?

Thanks

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem but this is probably relevant: `build/whatever.shp` and `./build/whatever.shp` are equivalent relative paths. A relative path is relative to the current working directory, not to where the script file is. You change the current working directory with `cd` builtin.

Comment: Hello, yes is relevant I edit the question to try to explain it better. I would like to create the folder build with the files in windows too not just in the root path in Ubuntu